# compare string in R

Tags: r, string, count

I'm currently working on a programming project in R (for school) and I'm using a data set made of a large quantity of LastFm users (an application that collects data when you're using a media player). 
I want to work on an eventual link between 2 variables present in the dataset which are the "nickname" and the "real name". To do so, I would like to compute a variable that represents the rate of similarity between the characters.

As an example take one individual (regardless of the other variables):

```
name = 'chris meller'
nickname = 'mellertime'
```

So far, tried to sort the strings in order to to check for identical characters one by one but I'm stuck here. What i found is just a way to to check if "name" is present inside "nickname" with different kind of functions.

```
>paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(name, ""))), collapse = "")
[1] "eeeillmmrt"
>paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(nickname, ""))), collapse = "")
[1] " ceehillmrrs"
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to count the number of identical letters between 2 character strings, regardless of the order?

I would like to end with something like this:

```
function(a,b)
[1] 0.63
# a,b are 2 character strings
```

where the result is the ratio of the number of identical character between the two strings divided by the number of characters in the real name.

Comment: Count letters with `table(strsplit('eeeillmmrt', '')[[1]])`, but edit distance (see `?adist`) would probably be more useful.

Comment: @alistaire thanks for the tip, i never heard abour Levenshtein distance which is used in adist, if i can't find my way i'll probably make something with Levenshtein.

Comment: @allstaire, could you provide more insight into implementing `adist`? I couldn't get it to return what the OP was looking for.  I even tried dabbling a bit in the `stringdist` package, but was unsuccessful in obtaining a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SimilarityRatio <- function(wholeName, nickname, matchCase) {

    n1 <- sort(strsplit(paste(strsplit(wholeName, " ")[[1]], collapse = ""), "")[[1]])
    n2 <- sort(strsplit(paste(strsplit(nickname, " ")[[1]], collapse = ""), "")[[1]])

    if (!matchCase) {
        n1 <- tolower(n1)
        n2 <- tolower(n2)
    }

    MyLen <- tempLen <- length(n1)
    j <- 1L
    numMatch <- 0L

    while (j <= tempLen) {
        test1 <- n1[j] %in% n2
        if (test1) {
            myRemove <- min(which(n2 %in% n1[j]))
            n1 <- n1[-j]
            n2 <- n2[-myRemove]
            numMatch <- numMatch + 1L
            tempLen <- tempLen - 1L
        } else {
            j <- j+1L
        }
    }

    numMatch/MyLen
}
```

Below are some test cases:

```
> SimilarityRatio("chris meller", "mellertime", FALSE)
[1] 0.6363636
> SimilarityRatio("SuperMan3000", "The3Musketeers", FALSE)
[1] 0.5
> SimilarityRatio("SuperMan3000", "The3Musketeers", TRUE)
[1] 0.4166667
> SimilarityRatio("should a garbage collection be performed immediately", "same expression can vary considerably depending on whether", FALSE)
[1] 0.7608696
```

Comment: Man it works perfectly, i am so grateful ! Thanks a lot.